# Visual Basic: Limit Textbox to specific characters

Tags: vb.net

What im trying to do, is to have a Windows Form Applications that, once a number is written in textbox and the accept button is pressed, will open another windows form where another number is written in another textbox and the second button will pressed, it will show a third form, will should only accept four digits "+" "-" "*" "/" each representing a basic math operation, however, im facing two problems at the moment.

For the first two boxes, I was able to made it so it only allows numbers, the problem is, I cant delete a number once its written, and I can type several "." for a floating number, which means that I can write numbers like "5136....5.25" which will obviously lead to an error when the calculation at the end is done. I havent found a way to limit that "." to only one, and I cant fix the delete, or backstep button either.
This is the code im using.

```
'Button
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Form4.n1 = TextBox1.Text
    Me.Hide()
    Form2.Show()
End Sub
'Textbox
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    e.Handled = Not (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Or e.KeyChar = "." Or Asc(e.KeyChar = "8"))
End Sub
```

Now with the third windows form I have another problem, I need to limit it to only accept "+" "-" "*" or "/" (only one of them, not more, and no numbers or characters either)

I feel the solution for these problems is the same, I need to limit somehow the numbers of "." and simbols to only one, and I need to limit the simbols in the third box to only those four.

Any ideas? Also, im quite a newbie, so any tips or explication will be quite appreciated, even if it makes the answer longer

Comment: Something like: `dim keys = "+-*/" if not (keys.Contains(e.KeyChar)) e.Handled = true`. You can find a lot of questions related to this matter.

Comment: I saw them but none of them work, I could still type sevaral "." or "+"

Comment: Add an `AndAlso` condition to check the current TextBox.Text content against the Key entered, in a similar way. You may want to move to the `KeyDown` event. In that case, set `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` instead of `e.Handled = true` to cancel the key pressed.

Comment: How about the TextBox can only be a number checked in the `Validating` event with `Double.TryParse()`. Then have a ComboBox in between the the number boxes with the operators.

Answer (score 0):

I recently have had to deal with something related with the issue. I coded a subroutine that checks characters that are inserted into de TetBox and depending the situation, it will allow us to type it or not.

In the code bellow I check if the key that has been pressed is the dot, ".". Then, I check if there is a previous dot on the Textbox. I use the method `IndexOf` which returns the position of the character. If it returns "-1", it means that there is no dot in the Textbox, so we can type it.

```
 If e.KeyChar = "." Then   
     If textBox.Text.IndexOf(".") = -1 Then   
         e.Handled = False
 Else                                        
     e.Handled = True
 End If
```

If you try to type another dot after the first one is typed, the line `textBox.Text.IndexOf(".")` Will return a value different from -1, so we won't be able to type it.

Regarding to delete button, I used the following lines to manage control keys:

```
If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
   e.Handled = False
Else
```

You can try to use this approach to limit the symbols in your third form, changing (dot) "." for the keys you need to be exclusively used.